# Seaborn no ordena el gráfico de acuerdo al orden en el dataset

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

¡Hola!, qué tal.

Recientemente me he puesto a practicar con Seaborn, y he tenido el siguiente problema:

Tengo un dataset básico, que es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intento graficar un lineplot como sigue:

```
prueba = pd.read_csv('prueba.csv')
sns.lineplot(data=prueba, x="mes", y="cantidad")
```

Donde **pd** y **sns** son el alias para pandas y seaborn, respectivamente.

Resulta que cuando grafica el dataset, lo hace como en la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo cual no es lo que necesito. Necesitaría que me grafique en orden las etiquetas del eje x. Es decir, que figuren así: "**marzo, abril, mayo, junio, julio**" (que es como los tengo ordenado en el dataset) y no "**mayo, marzo, junio, julio, abril** ".

Intenté con el argumento **sort=False** pero no hubo resultado alguno.

¿Alguna idea?

Desde ya gracias, Ciro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Muchas gracias a todos por tomarse un tiempo y responder.

Resolví el problema. Lo que pasó fue que tenía desactualizado Seaborn.
Como uso conda, lo actualicé con

```
conda update seaborn
```

Y ¡Ualá!, se solucionó.

Answer (score 1):

Debes agregar la opción `sort=False`.

```
sns.lineplot(data=prueba, x="mes", y="cantidad",sort=False)
```

Comment: ¿Por qué se tiene que hacer esto para solucionar el problema?

Comment: @Gabitohh porque evita que seaborn aplique el ordenamiento por defecto de strings al eje X

Answer (score 1):

Por defecto estamos obteniendo algo parecido pero en diferente orden.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

prueba = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv')
sns.lineplot(data=prueba, x="mes", y="cantidad")
plt.show()
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El resultado es en este orden (abril, julio, junio, marzo y mayo). No en el orden correcto de acuerdo al dataset.

Sin embargo creo que deberias de usar matplotlib para mostrar el gráfico por que al agregar la opción sort=False si funciona:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

prueba = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv')
#tr_df = pd.DataFrame({'Mes':prueba["mes"], 'Cantidad':prueba["cantidad"]})
#sns.lineplot(data=tr_df, x="Mes", y="Cantidad", sort=False)

sns.lineplot(data=prueba, x="mes", y="cantidad", sort=False)
plt.show()
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Orden del dataset:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Versión de Python = 3.8.3 Seaborn = 0.10.1  Matplotlib = 3.2.2

Uso anaconda. Suerte.